# ZF2 translate formelement button

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I have a form which is build with fieldsets and the translate is working well for the label and the placeholders on the form elements. The translator is initiated in the bootstrap and the form fields are translated on the fly. The only text which is not translated is the value in the submit button. The value exists in my .po .mo files.

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'btnSubmit',
        'type' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'Add',
            'id' => 'btnSubmit',
            'class' => 'btn blue'
        ),
    ));
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Try `'value' => _('Add'),`

Answer (score 0):

In the view the submit button must be of type formSubmit instead of formInput...